# How to wait for a "SaveAs" operation to complete?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm working on a VBA script that SaveAs all slides of a PPT as MP4 videos.
Until now, everything works fine, except that everytime I launch the script, I hit the 10 videos queue cap. To prevent this, I would like to find a way to stop the script until Powerpoint finishes to export the video, then repeats the process as long as there are videos in the Powerpoint.

The code :

```
Sub export()

    Dim Default, NameValue As Integer
    Dim BoxMessage, BoxTitle As String

    ' InputWindow, to get slide number
    BoxTitle = "Fenetre input valeur minimale"
    BoxMessage = "Rentrer le numero de la premiere slide exportee."

    BoxValue = InputBox(BoxMessage, BoxTitle, "Exemple : 20")

    ' Hide all slides
    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True
    Next

    ' For each slide, show the slide, SaveAs a videoMP4, hide the slide
    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

        If BoxValue <> 1 Then
            If i = 1 Then
                NameValue = BoxValue
            Else: NameValue = BoxValue + i
            End If
            
        Else: NameValue = i
        End If
        
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = False
        ActivePresentation.SaveAs "s" & NameValue & ".mp4", ppSaveAsMP4
        
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True
    Next

End Sub
```

I saw "Application.Wait", but I don't know how much time an export would take (I work with heavy powerpoints, and exports may take between 20s and 90s), and how to get that info. I cannot use DIR, since when you're exporting a video, Powerpoint already creates a file with the appropriate name in the appropriate directory.

Comment: You can handle this by using a DoEvents within a loop

Comment: @BugHunter By adding "DoEvents" after "ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True" ?
I'm trying to find a good documentation on how it works, but I don't find anything useful enough...

Comment: Here is Microsoft's page on DoEvents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function It's the SaveAs function that will need the delay, so try DoEvents immediately after that statement.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Tried it and it's not working as intended. It seems DoEvents does wait for the SaveAs function to conclude, but the export is not included.
Well, I'll search for external methods to check the state of the export. Thanks anyway !

Comment: make this a separate sub: `ActivePresentation.SaveAs "s" & NameValue & ".mp4", ppSaveAsMP4` and it will be forced to save it before doing something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a reliable method to check if the export is done before trying to export other slides. I think it's because VBA does not support this kind of precision.
So instead, I'll check around Powershell and such, to see if there are solutions to my problem.

Comment: VBA has no way of knowing when a save is done. In your case, just increase the delay by testing until you find that all slides are saved reliably.

Comment: Have a look at Shyam Pillai's page about this: http://skp.mvps.org/2010/ppt015.htm 
He explains how to poll VBA's CreateVideoStatus property to tell whether it's in progress/done etc.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Cannot, since the slides can take between 10s to 300s. I could try to find a middle value, but it would sacrifice a lot of time.